# Rasji quoting IBN-Saruq on the word 'keri'.

Tags: sources-mekorot, commentaries, rashi

I found [this](https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/stubbornness-and-chance/) explanation online:

> Rashi quotes the 10th Century grammarian Menachem (ben IBN-Saruq), who
>   derives keri from a two-letter root k–r, meaning “prevent, refuse,
>   withhold.” Thus, Hashem warns–If you walk with Me in refusal, I will
>   withhold My protection from you.

First of all I would like to know the source from where Rasji got this quote of IBN-Saruq, Secondly I would like to know if this quote is based on a verse from the Tenach, or if they are his own interpretation.

Comment: Rashi quotes Menachem pretty often. What’s unique that you ask it here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rashi ([Leviticus 26:21](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/olam_hatanah/mefaresh.asp?book=3&perek=26&mefaresh=rashi)) quotes Menachem in the following words

> ומנחם פירש: 
>   לשון מניעה.
>   וכן (משלי כה יז) הוקר רגלך.
>   וכן יקר רוח (משלי יז כז).
>
> Menachem interpreted [the word קרי] from the language of prevention, as in "withhold (הוקר) your feet" (Proverbs 25:17), and "one who withholds (יקר) speech" (Proverbs 17:27).

Menachem (in his [Machberet](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=36818&st=&pgnum=199), s.v. קר) gives this interpretation in the second meaning of the root קר, connecting the words quoted by Rashi, along with Psalms 49:9 and Isaiah 13:12, with the explanation "עניין מניעה המה" ("they have to do with prevention").